# CRM2011 Appointment end time value different between form and database when all day event checked

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

there is a check box - All Day Event - in appointment form, if check it, the end time got problem, for example, in the form end time is "2013-05-22", but in the database the value is "2013-05-23"; There is no issue if all day event is unchecked. Anyone knows why?

[image: The End Time and Due Date difference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:I saw your screenshot, 5/23/13 12:00 AM is midnight, so the time is correct.

CRM 2011 stores the datetime values in UTC format, when you read the values directly from SQL or Web Services you need to convert to the localtime value.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't think it is the reason. I attached the screenshot, do you know why this two date different?

Comment: I don't think so, why here showing "5/23/13 12:00AM" instead of "5/22/13 11:59PM"?

Comment: because 5/23/13 12:AM is the midnight, and for an all day event midnight is included. Please read these wikipedia articles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_notation#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight